# Perform Basic Arithmetic in single text box

Tags: c#

In visual c#,

I have a textbox and a button. When you enter a arithmetical operation in the textbox (eg "1+1") and click the button,

I want to 1+1 value in the textbox to change and be replaced with the answers of the arithmetic( that is 2)

So if you input 10 - 4 in the text box and press the button, the same textbox should change the value to 6.

I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: of course this is possible

Comment: Can this question be closed?

Answer (score 0):

your textbox has a .Text property pertaining the current string value. You will want to map a conversion and calculation to an event such as pressing enter or clicking a button.

One of the simplest ways to do this is use the Compute method of the DataTable class.

I have concatenated a statement which can do this on 1 line

```
myTextBox.Text = $"{new DataTable().Compute($"{myTextBox.Text.Trim()}", "")}";
```

This can be implemented in a number of ways, here's how I would do it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Calculate_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        InputTextbox.Text = Evaluate(InputTextbox.Text);
    }

    private string Evaluate(string equation) {
        try {
            return $"{new DataTable().Compute($"{equation.Trim()}", "")}";
        } catch (Exception Ex) {
            MessageBox.Show($"{Ex.Message}\n\n{equation.Trim()}", Ex.Source, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void InputTextbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13) {
            InputTextbox.Text = Evaluate(InputTextbox.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to c#, I'm not  very sure what to do

Is this right `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            textBox1.Text = $"{new DataTable().Compute($"{textBox1.Text.Trim()}", "")}";

        }`
?

Comment: I have added an example of how this could be implemented

Comment: I'm having errors on this line
`$"{new DataTable().Compute($"{equation.Trim()}", "")}";`

and this line
`MessageBox.Show($"{Ex.Message}\n\n{equation.Trim()}", Ex.Source, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }`

Comment: What seems to be the problem, this worked perfectly on a blank winform application?

Comment: I cannot help without information, I have already answered the question above